# is it possible to disable all previous years before 2015 in jquery date picker

Tags: jquery-ui

Please let me know if 
is it possible to disable all previous years before 2015 in jquery date picker

I have tried to use

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: false
    });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e5cvA/41/

Comment: Use the `minDate` option. [See this update](http://jsfiddle.net/e5cvA/43/).

Answer (score 2):

use `minDate` .

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      minDate: "01/01/2015",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: false
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this help.

```
   $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
           minDate: new Date(2015, 01, 1), dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', maxDate: new Date(2015, 12, 31)
        });
      });
```